# When would the use of re.search over re.findall in Python Regex make sense?

Tags: python, regex

I understand the technical difference between using `re.search` and `re.findall` in Python, but would someone with more experience explain situations in which you might use `re.search` over just using `re.findall` for regex parsing?

Comment: `re.findall` can be understood as python way of handling global matches..if you just want to find out where there exists a pattern in a string, you can use `re.search`

Comment: `re.search` == "find the first match", `re.findall` == "find all the matches"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation

> re.search(pattern, string, flags=0) :- Scan through string looking for
>   the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a
>   match, and return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if
>   no position in the string matches the pattern; note that this is
>   different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the
>   string.

i) If you just want to find whether there exists a pattern in string, you can use `re.search` e.g.

```
a+ in string abcdaa
```

will tell whether there is one or more than one `a` present in the string `abcaa`. If the match is found, it will return a MatchObject that string is found otherwise `None`. It won't check for any further occurrences of the pattern. So, if you use `re.search('a+', 'abcdaa').group(0)` you will only get `a` for string `abcdaa`

On the other hand, `re.findall` will return all matches that are found in a string, like `[a, aa]` for the string `abcdaa`. So, we can say that `re.findall` is python way of using `g` flag which finds all matches.

ii) One may argue that why not use `re.findall` to find all the matches and if the list is non-empty, then we can say that pattern exists.

In that case, `re.findall` will be (*much*) slower than `re.search`.

**Comparison** (*Processor* - **Intel® Core™ i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz × 4**, *Memory* - **7.7 GiB**)

On a string of size `10000000`, using the following code

```
import re
import time

st = "".join(str(n) for n in range(10000000))

start_time = time.time()
re.search(r"1+", st)
first_time = time.time()
print("Time taken by re.search = ", first_time - start_time, "seconds")

re.findall(r"1+", st)
second_time = time.time()
print("Time taken by re.findall = ", second_time - first_time, "seconds")
```

Output was

```
Time taken by re.search =  0.00011801719665527344 seconds
Time taken by re.findall =  1.7739462852478027 seconds
```

So, if we *just want to know* whether there is a pattern that exists in a string, its favorable to use `re.search`.

Comment: Thanks for an answer that gives me more to consider as well.

Comment: @McLeodx glad to help

Comment: I think you meant `re.findall` in the second print statement